# How to get Node status HighLevelRESTClient ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I am using the Java HighLevelRestClient to connect to my ElasticSearch.I was working on a task to get the health status of each nodes.

Tried with :

```
private string getHighLevelClientInfo(){
try{
ClusterHealthResponse res=restHighLevelClient.cluster().health(new ClusterHealthRequest(),RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
return res.getStatus.name();
}
catch(Exception e){
return "Error";
}
}
```

While doing so, i was getting all Cluster related information with Status as "Green" and number of nodes=3.

Any help, how to get the node specific information with node status.

Thanks

Comment: any luck here???

Comment: ended up with getting clusterHealth status..

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of node health status, it's a cluster health status which is made up of all the indices health status which again in turn made of shard health status.

I guess, you are looking for [node stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html), which will print each node stats like, how CPU, memory, various queue size, and several other information.